# Are all continuous linear operators on the space of entire functions "simple"?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, oa.operator-algebras, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\langle \operatorname{Ent},+,\cdot \rangle$ be the (complex) vector space of entire functions.

For all members $n$ of $\{1,2,3,...\}$, define $||\cdot ||_n : \operatorname{Ent} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $||f||_n = \operatorname{sup}(\{|f(z)| : |z|\leq n\})$.

$\big\langle \operatorname{Ent},+,\cdot,\{||.||_n : n\in \{1,2,3,...\}\} \big\rangle$ is a Frechet space.

For all complex numbers $z_0$ and members $g$ of $\operatorname{Ent}$, the operators $L_1,...,L_4 : \operatorname{Ent} \to \operatorname{Ent}$ defined by

$(i) \quad (L_1(f))(z) = g(z)\cdot f(z)$

$(ii) \quad (L_2(f))(z) = f(g(z))$

$(iii) \quad (L_3(f))(z) = f'(z)$

$(iv) \quad (L_4(f))(z) = \displaystyle\int_0^z f$

are all continuous and linear.

Let $S$ be the set of all functions obtainable by the above.

Let $\mathbf{L}$ be continuous operator algebra on $\operatorname{Ent}$.

Let $T$ be the closure of $S$ as a sub-algebra of $\mathbf{L}$.

Does $\:$  $T = \mathbf{L}$ $\:$  ?

If no, is $T$ dense in $\mathbf{L}$? (uniform operator topology)

If no again, is $T$ dense in $\mathbf{L}$ in some weaker topology?

Comment: It seems to me that you forget the following operators:
$$(L_6(f))(z)=f\circ g(z),$$
where $g\in$Ent is given.

Comment: Why would you expect this? You mean probably $S$ being the algebra generated by the operators? $S$ will seperate points using a Taylor expansion in $0$, but how would you get $f(g(z))$ or $g(f(z))$, e.g. start $f( \alpha z)$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Denis, that cuts it down to $L_1,...,L_4$.  (as I just edited to reflect)

Comment: What about restricting your functions to a compact subset of the reals and Fourier transforming it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a function $u(z)$ that is defined and holomorphic for $|z|>R$, with $u(z)\to 0$ as $z\to\infty$.  You can then define $L_u:\text{Ent}\to\mathbb{C}$ by $L_u(f)=\oint_C f(z)u(z)\\,dz$, where $C$ is a circle around the origin of radius $R'>R$.  This only depends on the germ of $u$ at $\infty$.  I think one can show that this gives an isomorphism from the space of germs to the dual of $\text{Ent}$.  There are theorems of this type in the following book:

```
 \bib{MR745622}{book}{
    author={Luecking, D. H.},
    author={Rubel, L. A.},
    title={Complex analysis},
    series={Universitext},
    note={A functional analysis approach},
    publisher={Springer-Verlag},
    place={New York},
    date={1984},
    pages={vii+176},
    isbn={0-387-90993-1},
    review={\MR{745622 (86d:30002)}},
 }
```

However, I am not 100% sure if they apply to the whole plane or just to bounded subsets.  Anyway, for a holomorphic function $u(z,w)$ with suitable domain we can now define an operator $T_u:\text{Ent}\to\text{Ent}$ by $T_u(f)(z)=\oint_C u(z,w)f(w)\\,dw$, and using the description of $\text{Ent}^*$ it should follow that this gives all possible continuous operators on $\text{Ent}$.